# ContentDistributionTrigger after insert ContentDownloadUrl null

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I have a ContentDistributionTrigger trigger after insert & update which when fired has a null value for ContentDownloadUrl.

The ContentDistribution is created in a  ContentDocumentLinkTrigger as such:

```
ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
cd.Name = (String)link.LinkedEntityId + ' logo' ;
cd.ContentVersionId = // my id
cd.RelatedRecordId = link.LinkedEntityId;
cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload = true;
cd.PreferencesPasswordRequired = false;
insert cd;
```

Then in my ContentDistributionTrigger:

```
trigger ContentDistributionTrigger on ContentDistribution ( after insert, after update ) {

    for (ContentDistribution cd : Trigger.new) {
        System.debug(cd.ContentDownloadUrl);
    }
}
```

debugs as "null"

Is the ContentDownloadUrl generated after the after insert trigger fires? If so, why don't I catch it in the "after update" run of this trigger?

Thank you,

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: are you running at V40+ ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to requery the object based on the trigger context with the fields you want in order to get their values.

```
List<ContentDistribution> contextList = [ select id, DistributionPublicUrl, ContentDownloadUrl, ContentDocumentId from ContentDistribution where id in :Trigger.new ];
```

And now you can work with contextList instead of Trigger.new.

Comment: why is this an answer? the field `ContentDownloadUrl` is in the trigger context. Your answer normally applies to fetching lookup objects. Have you observed for this object in particular that a SOQL query on the triggered records makes the fields available?

Comment: Yes I have. I had the same issue as the OP where the value was null in the trigger.new context but present when I requeried.

Comment: fascinating - I'm stunned